# Game of Life, I cant get the rules to apply. Java

Tags: java

I'm a java programming student, we've only been studying for around two months and our teacher gave us an assignment.

He made "The Game of Life" and gave us the task of implying the rules that will affect all the pixels.

I've succeeded in getting the pixels to move (somewhat) they're not exactly behaving as they should. either they form gigantic forms that cover the entire screen or they just shrivel up an become static.

So from my conclusion, something is wrong with how I apply the rules or something is wrong with how I count neighbors.

Here's the code.

How I initiate my code:

```
protected void applyRules(int[][] s, int[][] ns) {



try {

for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) {

for (int y = 0; y < s[0].length; y++) {

    countNeighbors(s, x, y);
    liveOrDie(s, x, y);

    ns[x][y] = s[x][y];


}

}
}catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
System.out.println("Error");
}   
}
```

Here is my countNeighbors:

```
private int countNeighbors(int[][] s, int x, int y) {

    int neighbors = 0;

    try {
        //NW
    if(s[x+1][y-1] == 1) {
        neighbors += 1;
        System.out.println("1");
        //W
    }if(s[x][y-1] == 1) {
        neighbors += 1;
        System.out.println("2");
        //SW
    }if(s[x-1][y-1] == 1) {
        neighbors += 1;
        System.out.println("3");
        //S
    }if(s[x-1][y] == 1) {
        neighbors += 1;
        System.out.println("4");
        //SE
    }if(s[x-1][y+1] == 1) {
        neighbors += 1;
        System.out.println("5");
        //E
    }if(s[x][y+1] == 1) {
        neighbors += 1;
        System.out.println("6");
        //NE
    }if(s[x+1][y+1] == 1) {
        neighbors += 1;
        System.out.println("7");
        //N
    }if(s[x+1][y] == 1) {
        neighbors += 1;
        System.out.println("8");
}
    }catch  (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

        }

    return neighbors;
    }
```

And at last my liveOrDie method:

```
 private int liveOrDie(int[][] s, int x, int y) {

    int state = 0;

            try {


            if((s[x][y] == 1) && (countNeighbors(s, x, y) < 2 || 
 countNeighbors( s, x, y) > 3)) {

                    state = 0;
                    s[x][y] = state; 



            }if ((s[x][y] == 0) && (countNeighbors(s, x, y) == 3)) {

                state = 1;

                s[x][y] = state;


            }if ((s[x][y] == 1) && (countNeighbors(s, x, y) == 2 || 
countNeighbors(s, x, y) == 3)) {

                state = s[x][y];

                s[x][y] = state;



            }
            }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

            }


return state;
}
```

Comment: On a quick glance, it looks like you're making the common mistake of changing `s` while iterating over it. It looks like you do have a copy of `s` (`ns`), but your `liveOrDie` still mutates `s`. You need to make a copy of `s`, then read from `s`, but write to the copy of `s`.

Comment: Also, you should *not* be catching `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s; especially considering you're just ignoring it. If you get that exception, it means your program is broken. You shouldn't be ignoring exceptions that are telling you that something is wrong with your program.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I feel obliged to warn you that posting an assignment solution (or a significant part thereof) on this or any other public site may get you into trouble with your school if they find it.  To avoid this, please reduce any code to a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!

Do you mean that i need to write my state in liveOrDie as a new array? ns[x][y] = state; ?

Comment: @ErikLundin In that function, you do `s[x][y] = state;`, which changes `s`. You cannot change `s` while reading from it. That messes with the patterns that develop.

Comment: @ErikLundin And yes. You need to change the copy while reading from the original.

Comment: Joe C, thanks for the heads up, It's good that I'm here to learn not to try to cheat. I understand that it's quite sensitive when it comes to school work.